# Mailto: or alternative for sending an email

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-email

When a user clicks on an image, I would like an email to be sent with a link related to that image.

Here is the html code, currently the email opens but the link is not attached:

```
    <a href="mailto:?Subject=You%20have%20been%20sent%20a%20MixTape&body=Hello">
      <div id="resultsTwo"></div>
      <p id="linkTwo"></p>
    </a>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered to choose the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can not add an attachment to a message with the mailto: URL scheme due security reasons:

> The user agent interpreting a mailto URL SHOULD choose not to create a
>   message if any of the headers are considered dangerous (...) Only the
>   Subject, Keywords, and Body headers are believed to be both safe and
>   useful. mailto: only supports header values or text/plain content.

According to [RFC 2368](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html).

If you want to send an email with an attachement you will have to do it through server side.